# About Arago spot and the fringe distance formula

Tags: optics, diffraction

The Arago spot in the center of the shade seams mysterious because it is due to diffraction and in diffraction of a slit the distance between fringes are ruled by the formula $D=л.L/d$ where $л$ is the wavelength, $L$ the distance to screen, $d$ the slit, and $D$ the fringe distance. Now in Arago arrangement d is big, so D would be small - e.g unobservable by naked eye. So the central maximum would not be followed by darkness but by the second maximum, third etc. and so the intensity would diminish gradually. Why there are not these higher order maxima observable in this fenomenon?

Comment: Why do you say they are not observable ?  I'm sure they would be.  Also consider in the double slit experiment if the slits are far apart the fringes are also harder to observe  .... but a sensitive camera would still see them.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say they are not observable ? I'm sure they would be. Also consider in the double slit experiment if the slits are far apart the fringes are also harder to observe .... but a sensitive camera would still see them.

Comment: I think rather d is different for the different pairs of points from the edge of the Arago disk so interference from more than 2 points away from the center is very rare. So two or may be few more 'rays' will meet interference condition but will give much less intensity to be noticed well.

Comment: And also many ray will meet negative interference or some half conditions.

Comment: Arago spot is very similar to Airy disk, both are caused by the large circle of the aperture or disk.  Maybe its better to consider Feynman path integral theory: 1) every photon determines its own path (they do not cancel) 2) performing the integral shows preferred paths for photons, the calculation shows the paths that are integer multiples of the wavelength are more probable and therefore brighter.

Comment: I looked at a photo of Arago spot and when increasing it the circles around the spot got  visible. They are on equal spacing from each other. But I wonder what is the distance between the points on the disk that interfere, because this distance vary from 0 to the diameter of the disk.

Comment: As for Feynman paths it is a good way for calculations but the problem is that the photons can not calculate these angles of preference which occur on the disk as they must have traveled the distance to the screen beforehand.

Comment: I see in wikipedia there are many formulas .... also they talk about near field Fresnel diffraction.  For Feynman theory ... yes there are possibly virtual photons (forces) that set up the path in advance of the energy transfer (real photon) .... maybe it is not so mysterious.